# How do I get navigation bar's dropdown to stay when hovering over the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple website with a simple navigation bar, but it seems like a very daunting task after much research.
When hovering over any of the buttons, it will display a dropdown to show more options.
I have got that working fine, but how would I go about making the dropdown stay when I hover over the contents of the dropdown?

Basically when the cursor leaves the navigation's bar button and onto the dropdown menu, it doesn't disappear.

I read that it's possible with jQuery, but I want to do it in JavaScript alone if it's possible, even if it's lengthy.

The navbar's hover itself works, but whatever I tried to keep the dropdown there when hovering on it, keeps bugging everything out.

This is the code I have, and that I have tried:

```js
document.getElementById("server").onmouseover = function() {
 serverMouseOver()
 };
document.getElementById("server").onmouseout = function() {
 serverMouseOut()
 };
function serverMouseOver() {
 document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").className += "animated fadeIn";
 };
function serverMouseOut() {
 document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").className += "animated fadeOut";
 };
document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").onmouseover = function() {
 serverDropdownMouseOver()
 };
document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").onmouseout = function() {
 serverDropdownMouseOut()
 };
function serverDropdownMouseOver() {
 document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.opacity = "1";
 };
function serverDropdownMouseOut() {
 document.getElementById("serverdropdownbox").style.opacity = "0";
 };
```

```css
   

#navbarbox   
   {
   clear: both;
   display: block;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 3.5vw;
   padding: 0vw 0 0 0;
   margin: 0;
   }
#navbar, #navbar ul
   {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 3.5vw;
   display: flex;
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
   margin: 0;
   }
   
#navbar span
   {
   height: 3.5vw;
   display: block;
   transform: skewX(15deg);
   }
   
#navbar li
   {
   color: white;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 1vw 3.95vw 1vw 3.95vw;
   margin: auto;
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
   font-size: 2.3vw;
   font-family: Jura;
   height: 2.5vw;
   transform: skewX(-15deg);
   }
   
#serverdropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   opacity: 0;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   }
   
#serverdropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 16vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 10.1vw;
   }
   
   
#serverdropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   background-color: white;
   }
   
#server
   {
   background-color: blue;
   }
   
#communitydropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   }
   
#communitydropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 19.7vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 26vw;
   }
   
   
#communitydropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   }
   
#community
   {
   background-color: brown;
   }   
#storedropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   }
   
#storedropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 13.6vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 45.65vw;
   }
   
   
#storedropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   }
   
#store
   {
   background-color: blue;
   }   
#downloadsdropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   }
   
#downloadsdropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 19.8vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 59.2vw;
   }
   
   
#downloadsdropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   }
   
#downloads
   {
   background-color: brown;
   }   
#contactdropdownbox
   {
   display: block;
   float: left;
   color: white;
   background-color: darkblue;
   width: 0;
   }
   
#contactdropdowncontent
   {
   list-style-type: none;
   width: 16vw;
   margin: 1vw 0 0 78.9vw;
   }
   
   
#contactdropdowncontent li
   {
   border: 1px solid white;
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 1vw 0 1vw 0;
   }
   
#contact
   {
   background-color: blue;
   }
   
.animated
   {
     animation-duration: 1s;
     animation-fill-mode: both;
   }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fadeOut {
  animation-name: fadeOut;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura" />
<body>


<!--Giga logo, top left-->
<img id="gigalogo"  src="images/gigalogo.png">

<!--Steam logo, top right-->
<div id="steamlogomainbox">
  <img id="steamlogo" src="images/steamlogo.png">
</div>

<!--navigation barrrrrr-->
<div id="navbarbox">
 <ul id="navbar">
  <a href="default.html"><li style="background-color: purple;"><span>Home</span></li></a>
  <a href="servers.html"><li id="server"><span>Servers</span></li></a>
  <a href="community.html"><li id="community"><span>Community</span></li></a>
  <a href="store.html"><li id="store"><span>Store</span></li></a>
  <a href="downloads.html"><li id="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></li></a>
  <a href="contact.html"><li id="contact"><span>Contact</span></li></a>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="serverdropdownbox">
 <ul id="serverdropdowncontent">
  <a href="serverlist.html"><li id="serverdropdownli">Server List</li></a>
  <li id="serverdropdownli">GigaDB</li>
  <li id="serverdropdownli">CS:GO</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="communitydropdownbox">
 <ul id="communitydropdowncontent">
  <a href="events.html"><li>Events</li></a>
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="storedropdownbox">
 <ul id="storedropdowncontent">
  <li>Credits</li>
  <li>Items</li>
  <li>VIP</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="downloadsdropdownbox">
 <ul id="downloadsdropdowncontent">
  <li>TF2</li>
  <li>CS:GO</li>
  <li>Minecraft</li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="contactdropdownbox">
 <ul id="contactdropdowncontent">
  <li>Contact Us</li>
  <li>Staff</li>
  <a href="https://steamcommunity.com/groups/gigagamings" target="_blank"><li>Steam Group</li></a>
  <li>Appeal Ban</li>
  <li>Links</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need JavsScript for this. Use the `:hover` pseudo-class. Search online for "suckerfish dropdowns" (that's the name of the technique).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - your HTML structure is invalid. `ul` tag can have only `li` as direct child, not `a`. So `ul > a > li` must be replaced to `ul > li > a`.

Second - you don't need JS for such simple menu. Have `ul > li > ul` as sub-menu and use `:hover` on `ul > li` to show your sub-menu.

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu > li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#menu > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <span>Servers</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="server1.html">Server 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="server2.html">Server 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="server3.html">Server 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```